# ModalPopup disappears if i Hover-over popover on my modalPopup

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover, bootstrap-modal

Got struck in strange problem here. I am using *bootstrap v2.3.1.* I have a `Modal Dialog box` and in that `Modal Dialog box` i have couple of `Popover` where user can hover the mouse and show some info but the problem i am facing is as soon as user takes his mouse out of `Popover`, my Modal Dialog box disappears.

I have debugged the code and can confirm `Modals Hide/Hidden` event is fired as soon as i take mouse out of popover. Seems to be some `jQuery` problem where instead of fading out popover text, its changes modal level data.

Has anyone had thing kind of problem?

some of you may suggest updating Bootstrap, i am afraid that will lead to testing the whole website which is quite stable with this version.

Comment: Can you show some code? Cannot reproduce the behaviour. How do you trigger the modal and popovers? A normal setup with modal / popover should **never** behave like this. And I dont think you should "upgrade" bootstrap 2.3.x is really fine.

Comment: we use a tool to create our question so every question that gets created, we add a div like this ````<a class="classname" tabindex="-1" data-original-title="Error" rel="popover" data-content="This field may not be left blank" href="#">
<i class="icon-warning-sign"></i>
</a>```` and then in js file initialize it as ````$('.classname').popover({ 'trigger': 'hover', 'placement': 'bottom' });````

Comment: no problem on stand alone forms, but when we display our form in ModalPopup, on mouse-out, the form disappears (or hidden method of modalpopup gets called)